# How's it possible that for two or more shapes given the same area, that each shape can have distinct perimeters?

Tags: area, geometry

I've just 'discovered' (of course am not the first though) a very strange property in geometry relating to the the relationship between the Area and the Perimeter of an object.

Say you have box A with dimensions of 50 x 25. The area is 1250, and the perimeter is 150.

Box B also has an area of 1250, but now it's dimensions are 10 x 125. However, it's perimeter is 270.

Given that the same amount of cake is in each box, where does the icing go? Or rather, given the area + perimeter, doesn't that equal to the amount of 'stuff' , after all, isn't the perimeter the same as the area, only on the outside, not the inside (though I suppose inside/outside, depth, doesn't exist in a 2D world...).

Actually, on a side note, how IS the perimeter measured, is it thought of as part of the content? Though if not, how is it measured, what is measured?

What's also fascinating is that this doesn't seem possible with circles, yet with any other object it seems that it is.

I look forward to the responses, as this seems to be quite counter-intuitive! Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: Imagine a square cake. Now cut it in half. Suddenly the cake has a larger perimeter but the same area! That's because it used to be that a part of the new perimeter was touching another part of the new perimeter, "canceling" both out, but that's no longer the case now.

Comment: There's a lot more skin on a snake than a rabbit... (of the same weight).

Comment: As a side note, it's possible to have infinite perimeter with finite area. That area can be then converted into any shape of finite area. Thinking about that more, you can come to the conclusion that a given area can have any perimeter

Comment: Made me think about the area of a triangle being proportional to its base and perpendicular height.  The 'slanted' edges are not used in the calculation for area but they are for the perimeter.  Its possible to fix the area but increase the perimeter by sliding the apex of the triangle parallel to the base.  For circles the radius is included in the area and circumference calculation and this trick isn't possible.

Comment: Huh, that actually makes sense. Like if you cut a box in half, you double count the perimeter of the part of the box that was cut in half. As I do 2x that dimension (the line running down the middle of the original box), and subtract it from the perimeter of the two smaller boxes, it seems that the perimeters add up!

Comment: Thanks Solo! You should add that as an answer :)

Comment: yes, the "cutting" idea is a great way to see it intuitively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are apparently in a 2D world here, so a “box” is in fact a rectangle, which has an area and a perimeter. The most trivial answer to “why aren't the two always proportional” would be a counter-question of “why should they”.

[image: Illustration]

But this is all about intuition, so imagine you start with a cardboard square of $10\times10$ units. It has a perimeter of $4\times 10=40$ units. Cut it in half and you obtain two rectangles of $10\times 5$ units, each of which has $30$ units perimeter. That's because your newly introduced cut created new perimeter in what used to be the inside, namely twice the length of the cut, i.e. $2\times10=20$ units. OK, two rectangles are not one rectangle, but if you glue them together along their short edge, you loose $2\times5=10$ units of perimeter which now are glued and therefore contained in the inside, but you still have $2\times(5+20)=50$ units of perimeter; more than what you started with. So in this example, the cardboard is the “stuff” whose amount stays fixed, and the perimeter depends on the shape, can be gained by cutting and lost by gluing.

But there is the opposite case as well. Instead of a cardboard square, take a piece of string, $40$ units of length. If you form a square, you will get the same square as above, covering an area of $100$ square units. But if you create other figures with the string, you get other areas. So here the perimeter is what stays fixed, and the area varies.

There are a lot of topics related to this relation between perimeter and area:

- Of all rectangles with given area, the square has [least perimeter](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565507/35416). Conversely, of all rectangles with given perimeter, the square has largest area.
- Of all shapes with given area, the circle has least perimeter. Conversely…
- For a given area, the perimeter can become arbitrary large. One can even define objects with finite area but infinite perimeter, like e.g. the fractal [Koch snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake).
- Measuring perimeter in real life can depend a lot on scale. The classical question here is [how long is the coast of Britain?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Long_Is_the_Coast_of_Britain%3F) (Which is also the name of a paper by Mandelbrot.)

> Actually, on a side note, how IS the perimeter measured, is it thought of as part of the content? Though if not, how is it measured, what is measured?

The perimeter of a planar figure is a simple case of a [topological boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29) and as such *not* part of the “content” (i.e. interior) of the shape. As I just mentioned, measuring a boundaries in real life using a ruler can lead to results which depend on the ruler. So in most branches of mathematics, the problem is more one of *computing* the perimeter. One common approach starts by finding a piecewise parametric description of the perimeter, then integrating over that. But it depends a lot on what kind of shape you are talking about, how it is described.

> What's also fascinating is that this doesn't seem possible with circles, yet with any other object it seems that it is.

A circle has a fixed ratio between area and perimeter. So does the square. The class of all rectangles has no such ratio, but if you e.g. fix the aspect ratio of the rectangles, e.g. only consider 16:9 TV screens, then you again have a fixed ratio between area and perimeter. If you want a more flexible class containing circles, you could consider all ellipses. There again the ratio between area and perimeter depends on the actual shape (and [computing the perimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference) can be really hard). So it all depends on what family of shapes you consider, whether knowing the area fixes the perimeter (or vice versa) or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful response, you really went above and beyond in aiding my understanding with area, the relation that is has with the perimeter :)

Thanks again!